# Any API in android to normalize phone number

Tags: android

Is there any API in android which normalize phone numbers? e.g. when i look up phone number , some times there is 2223334444 some times, it is +2223334444

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has dedicated class for that purpose:

[android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)

Comment: But it does not strip the string down to MSISDN. There is a stripSeparators(String phoneNumber) method. But it considers '+' as a non-separator.

Comment: Because it is not a separator.

Comment: If your app supports an API < 21, you can simply copy that method to your project.

Comment: Link-only answers are not encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a part of Android, you might want to check out Google's [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).