# Handling phone numbers properly (storing, ideally using a unique form)

Tags: android, phone-number

This question is not specific to Android but I have included the tag.

I need to be able to store phone numbers in some sort of standard form (ideally a string) where equality can be tested/evaluated quickly (hence a string would be ideal)

I found some answers already, the best ones pointed to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html (I'm fine with using a library to do it for me)

BUT this isn't really good enough, I've tried a variety of format numbers, learnt about the Editable factory to use some of the static methods in that class, but they don't seem to return the form I was expecting.

I was expecting something like a phone-number-hash, that two inputs **representing** the same number would yield the same in this "standard form" and that one could dial this standard form and be fine. I thought that all the various +s and whatnot would be short-hands for this standard form.

I'm not sure if such a thing exists now.

I understand that some things mean "current area" (or country) which is why land-lines can ommit area codes, I expected a function that would return the format for the current location (but this doesn't apply to mobiles, if it were a land line to prepend the area code for example, this would be (closer) to the "standard form" I keep assuming exists)

I am pretty sure that some full-form for phone numbers exists, thinking about how the telephone system works (which I infer I admit) there ought to be a form that identifies a number uniquely across the whole planet, and when this is not the case (such as local calls from land-lines without area codes) it is an optimisation.

So I have two questions:

How can I "expand" a phone number to a unique string for that number, such that any alternate forms of writing that number (with spaces, an 0 or +44....) "expand" to this unique number?

Are there any ISO(/IEC?) (what's the O stand for?) standard documents with drafts open to the public? I've read the Wikipedia page (ages ago, I've spent so many hours wiki-browsing, and opened hundreds of tabs) but it covers history, or some information on formatting), I'd like to know more about the thing I've taken for granted now for some 8 years or so.

Additionally, why is Windows Phone 8 a tag? To make the 12 proud Lumina owners not feel left out? (It was suggested as a tag!)

**Addendum**

Unfortunately [Any API in android to normalize phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742464/any-api-in-android-to-normalize-phone-number) there are no solutions there (this includes libphonenumber) and my quest to find out has lead to some interesting reads:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_switch

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonblocking_minimal_spanning_switch

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange

and I still cannot conclude there isn't some "full form" for numbers.

I dare not create a solution that simply swaps +44 for an 0 and such.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question, I was reminded of Google's library called [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). Its Google's common library for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. It does the following things ( some of which seem what you might be able to use):

- Parsing/formatting/validating phone numbers for all countries/regions
  of the world.
- **getNumberType** - gets the type of the number based on
  the number itself; able to distinguish Fixed-line, Mobile, Toll-free,
  Premium Rate, Shared Cost, VoIP and Personal Numbers (whenever
  feasible).
- **isNumberMatch** - gets a confidence level on whether two
  numbers could be the same.
- **isPossibleNumber** - quickly guessing whether a number is a possible
  phonenumber by using only the length information, much faster than a
  full validation.
- **isValidNumber** - full validation of a phone number
  for a region using length and prefix information.
- **AsYouTypeFormatter** - formats phone numbers on-the-fly when users enter each digit.
- **PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder** - provides geographical information related to a phone number.

As far as international format of phone number is concerned, [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format is an recommended by International Telecommunication Union. It defines a numbering plan for the world-wide public switched telephone network and is a general format for international telephone numbers ( usually stats with `+` followed by country code, Area code and the number).

Using the above library, validity of all the phone numbers can be checked if you mention the international code along with the phone number ( example `1` for US & Canada). If you don't have the code but you know the country's name for which you want to check the number, then also you can validate. You can also convert all the valid numbers of 1 standard `E.164` format using this library. You can also 'expand' a number in Local National format of that particular country. You can save it as String as well. Although it does use `PhoneNumberUtils` that you mentioned in your question.

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately not, "used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich", I should have put a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742464/any-api-in-android-to-normalize-phone-number in the question, thanks for trying though.